# Assign Color of a .cs file to a solidcolorbrush in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm trying to define some colors for my own control. I generate one resources dictionary where I want to include 3 solid brushes. I want to define as its colors some colors I have define in a .cs file as a `System.Windows.Media.Color`. I don't know what I'm doing wrong, but I have tried several ways..

I think that I'm trying to "cast" one instance of a color as a string... So the code explotes. Does anybody knows which syntax is the correct in order to do that? Here is my code (the problem is located on line 15 (ResourcesDictionary)):

```
<TextBlock x:Class="PhanUtils.Interfaz.Wpf.Controles.Basicos.PhanLabel"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:PhanUtils.Interfaz.Wpf.Controles.Basicos"
         xmlns:paleta="clr-namespace:PhanUtils.Interfaz.Wpf.Paletas.Controles"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="25" d:DesignWidth="50" Background="Transparent" 
         MouseDown="TextBlock_MouseDown" MouseEnter="TextBlock_MouseEnter" MouseLeave="TextBlock_MouseLeave">

<TextBlock.Resources>
    <!-- Incluyo todos los colores requeirdos -->
    <ResourceDictionary x:Name="ColoresPhanGhost">
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ColorFuente" Color="{DynamicResource paleta:PaletaLabel.Texto_OLD}"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ColorDisable" Color="{StaticResource paleta:PaletaLabel.Deshabilitado}"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ColorLink" Color="{StaticResource paleta:PaletaLabel.Link}"/>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</TextBlock.Resources>

<TextBlock.Style>
    <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <!-- Caso deshabilitado -->
            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Aqua"/>
            </Trigger>

            <!-- Caso habilitado en que un link no se ha clickado -->
            <MultiTrigger>
                <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Condition Property="IsEnabled" Value="True"/>
                    <Condition Property="local:PhanLabel.EsLink" Value="True"/>
                    <Condition Property="local:PhanLabel.EstaClickado" Value="False"/>
                </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource ColorFuente}"/>
            </MultiTrigger>

            <!-- Caso habilitado en que un link ha sido clickado -->
            <MultiTrigger>
                <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Condition Property="IsEnabled" Value="True"/>
                    <Condition Property="local:PhanLabel.EsLink" Value="True"/>
                    <Condition Property="local:PhanLabel.EstaClickado" Value="True"/>
                </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="GreenYellow"/>
            </MultiTrigger>

            <!-- Cualquier otro caso -->
            <MultiTrigger>
                <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Condition Property="IsEnabled" Value="True"/>
                    <Condition Property="local:PhanLabel.EsLink" Value="False"/>
                </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"/>
            </MultiTrigger>

        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</TextBlock.Style>
```

Thanks!!

PD: You will see that there's only one reference to those brushes. This is because I was trying where the bug was, so I just disconect all parts excepting one (setter of the first multitrigger)

UPDATE 1: ColorsCode

```
    internal static Color Deshabilitado
    {
        get
        {
            // En función de la paleta, defino el color a devolver.
            switch (PaletaInterfaz.Paleta)
            {
                case PaletaInterfaz.Tipo_Paleta.Oscura: return Oscura_Label_Texto_Deshabilitado;

                case PaletaInterfaz.Tipo_Paleta.Original:
                default: return Original_Texto_Deshabilitado;
            }
        }
    }

    internal static Color Link
    {
        get
        {
            // En función de la paleta, defino el color a devolver.
            switch (PaletaInterfaz.Paleta)
            {
                case PaletaInterfaz.Tipo_Paleta.Oscura: return Oscura_Texto_Link;

                case PaletaInterfaz.Tipo_Paleta.Original:
                default: return Original_Texto_Link;
            }
        }
    }

    internal static Color Texto_OLD
    {
        get
        {
            // En función de la paleta, defino el color a devolver.
            switch (PaletaInterfaz.Paleta)
            {
                case PaletaInterfaz.Tipo_Paleta.Oscura: return Oscura_Texto;

                case PaletaInterfaz.Tipo_Paleta.Original:
                default: return Original_Texto;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: All properties are included as internal in a internal static class

Comment: `Color="{StaticResource paleta:PaletaLabel.Deshabilitado}` (or DynamicResource) won't work, because `paleta:PaletaLabel.Deshabilitado` is not a resource key. Try `Color="{x:Static paleta:PaletaLabel.Deshabilitado}`.

Comment: On the other hand I don't think if `Binding` can work in `ResourceDictionary`

Comment: i've tried too... on the other hand, im not sure  where it could work... It is possible to convert all static colors into brushes and call it into the code, into the setter??

Comment: You either do something completely wrong, or you show only part of the code related to the question.

You are accessing resource keys like `paleta: PaletaLabel.Link`.
First, there are no namespace prefixes in resource keys. At least I haven't come across this.
Second, show the `Resources` in which you create resources with these keys.